# Converting Complex SQL Joins into Rails ActiveRecord Query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have the following SQL which executes correctly in PGAdmin, but try as I might, I cannot get the join working and executing correctly.

```
SELECT "Reading_ID", "Pixel_ID", "Level", "Readings"."Time"
  FROM "PixelReadings"
    INNER JOIN "Readings" ON ("Reading_ID" = "Readings"."ID")
      INNER JOIN "Sources" ON ("Readings"."Source_ID" = "Sources"."ID")
        INNER JOIN location_mappings ON ("Sources"."ID" = "location_mappings"."source_id")
  WHERE ("Readings"."Time" BETWEEN '2016-07-25 06:03:07 UTC' AND '2016-07-26 06:03:07 UTC')
    AND "location_mappings"."location_id" = 16
    AND ("location_mappings"."use_order" = 0)
    AND "Pixel_ID" = ("location_mappings"."pixel_y" * 511) + "location_mappings"."pixel_x"
  ORDER BY ("Reading_ID") ASC
LIMIT 4;
```

Can anyone help with converting this into an ActiveRecord Query. I have 2 specific problems, trying to get

`.includes(readings: {sources: :location_mappings})`

And how to correctly format the 'where' methods. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

`"Reading_ID", "Pixel_ID", "Level"` are all the columns in the PixelReadings schema - I need all the PixelReading columns plus the Time column from the Readings table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are the table names are correctly set on your rails models?  I see that the table names are not in correspondence with the rails conventions. If you haven't set them, you can set em like this (do the same for all models that doesn't have table names different from rails conventions):

```
class PixelReading < ActiveRecord::Base
 self.table_name = "PixelReadings"
end
```

Your query would look something like this

```
PrixelReading
 .joins(readings: {sources: :location_mappings})
 .where("Readings.Time BETWEEN '2016-07-25 06:03:07 UTC' AND '2016-07-26 06:03:07 UTC'")
 .where(location_mappings: { location_id: 16, use_order: 0 })
 .where("Pixel_ID = (location_mappings.pixel_y * 511) + location_mappings.pixel_x")
 .order("PixelReadings.Reading_ID ASC")
 .select("PixelReadings.*, Readings.Time")
 .limit(4)
```

Comment: `readings` should be in a `includes` since he'll need to access it, no?

Comment: may be, I'm not entirely sure. From what i remember, `joins` and `includes` need not be used together but I could be wrong. Would be interesting to know if @Ash could tries and lets us know.

Comment: joins wouldn't make the record available. Once I do `pixel_reading.readings` Rails will load readings once again. With `includes`, those records are available. I also can't say what Rails will do with you stick the two of them together, but I'm sure that with `joins` they won't be available without a second query.

Comment: That is right, if we need eager loading, `includes` is needed. However, if we are to just reference the table in the query, we wouldn't need `includes` I guess.

Comment: Yep, we wouldn't. `joins` will help us search trough associations but it won't eager_load them.

Comment: Perfect. Although I had to use the singular versions of the associations in the join.  Also (weirdly) changing the "joins" to "includes" causes it to cease working.  Even more weirdly, using the joins works just fine and it can access 'Readings.Time' using a single eagerly loaded query.

But it works now - and thats the important thing. Thanks folks.

Comment: Glad it worked. I will edit to answer to have singular version in `joins`.